# Nginx + LimeSurvey:

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to secure my Limesurvey 2.0.5 admin page (running under Ubuntu 12.04, Nginx 1.19, PHP5.3.10, PHP-FPM).

The admin page should only be accessible from a specific subnet so in my conf I used allow 172.16.1.0/24

server conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    set $host_path "/opt/limesurvey";
    server_name  www.example.tld
    root $host_path;
    charset utf-8;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
            deny  all;
    }


    # admin page only for lan
    location ^~ /admin/ {
            allow 172.16.1.0/24;
            deny all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            try_files $uri index.php;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME      $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

If I'm connecting from a client outside of my LAN:

```
2014/10/20 13:04:54 [error] 3794#0: *137 access forbidden by rule, client: 1.2.3.4, server: www.example.tld, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", host: "2.3.4.5"
```

Connection from the inside:

```
2014/10/20 14:29:55 [error] 4165#0: *184 directory index of "/opt/limesurvey/admin/" is forbidden, client: 172.16.1.12, server: www.example.tld, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "2.3.4.5"
```

Access-Log without location /admin {

```
172.16.1.10 - - [20/Oct/2014:14:32:22 +0200] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36"
172.16.1.10 - - [20/Oct/2014:14:32:22 +0200] "GET /admin/authentication/sa/login HTTP/1.1" 200 4017 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36"
```

Limesurvey calls an index.php which relocates my request via:
`header( 'Location: ../index.php/admin' );`

If you need more information please ask

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what's the issue ?? You denied the first location to everyone and restricted the second to **`172.16.1.0/24`** while you are connecting from **`10.1.200.12`** as the log shows. Works as expected.

Comment: I just forgot to anonymize my client ip, sorry about that. I corrected my original post. My problem is that connection from outside working as expected, but my internal client, which is allowed, is getting the error directory index forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx thinks you are trying to list directory `/opt/limesurvey/admin` content  as you are not requesting any files in it and there's no forwarding to the php fallback.

Remove the `try_files` directive at server level. Add this location instead :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}
```

And change admin location to :

```
location ^~ /admin/ {
    allow 172.16.1.0/24;
    deny all;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Thats works, thanks to you, now i understand what nginx is doing internally :-)